# Troubles in chaining firebase functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having headache for some troubles in firebase.

```
var DocentiRef = firebase.database().ref('/Docenti/');            
var keyDocente = snapshot1.key; //I get this earlier, It's an userid
DocentiRef.child(keyDocente + "/prenotazioni/").orderByKey().on("child_added", function(snapshot2) {
  var keyFascia = snapshot2.key;
  console.log(snapshot2.key + "1");                                      
  var userPrenotazioniRef = firebase.database().ref('/Genitori/' + user.uid + "/prenotazioni/");
  userPrenotazioniRef.orderByKey().equalTo(keyFascia).on("child_added", function(snapshot3) {
    console.log(snapshot3.key + "2");
  });                           
});
```

I'm calling a function to get all the children's keys of a ref. Then I print them (and also a "1") in the console and I get something like:

key1 1

key2 1

key3 1

then I get in another ref the child who has "key1" as key, and I print that(I also add a "2" to make a difference in the console between the key of the first ref's child and the key of the second ref's child, that would have the same values). I also do this for key2 and key3. Now the console looks like:

key1 1

key2 1

key3 1

key1 2

key2 2

key3 2

The problem is that it should looks like:

key1 1

key1 2

key2 1

key2 2

key3 1

key3 2

How can i solve the problem and make the code works as It's intended to be? Thank you for any help!

Comment: Your code is actually doing exactly what I'd expect.  I think you're going to have a hard time changing the output to be what you want, since `on()` is asynchronous and doesn't deliver query results immediately.

Comment: @DougStevenson so I should take the way of the promises?

Comment: I don't know.  Actually you're not even dealing with promises at all here.  You would have to use `once()` to get a promise.  Maybe you can get your actual work done with the behavior these loops have now, but you're not really saying what is the actual problem to solve.

Comment: @DougStevenson the problem is  how to  archive the output I want using only firebase . However many thanks!